# Performance : which is faster calling reverse on a stack or popping items into an array

Tags: c#, performance

I was wondering which implementation would have better performance:

I need to clear all items out of a stack except the first 10 at the head.

These 10 must then be placed into the stack in their orginal order.

I thought of 2 approaches

the first:

```
FilterRecord[] records = new FilterRecord[10];

       for (int i = 0; i < records.Length; i++)
       {
           records[i] = _InternalCollection.Pop();
       }

       _InternalCollection.Clear();

       for (int i = records.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
           _InternalCollection.Push(records[i]);
       }
```

The second:

```
int count = _InternalCollection.Count - 10;
               _InternalCollection.Reverse();


               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
               {
                   _InternalCollection.Pop();
               }

               _InternalCollection.Reverse();
```

Any help or guidelines or other impemenations would be welcome.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity for you to do some benchmarking.  For your given example, the difference is probably negligible in the real world anyway.

Comment: Yeah I was being lazy, thought I could get an answer right away ,
perhaps by some one pointing out something glaringly obviously wrong in either  approach.

Comment: The second method actually doesn't work as intended. The Stack<T> class doesn't have a Reverse method. It's an extension method to IEnumerable<T>, so it would not affect the stack at all. A performance test would show that it's very fast, but that's because the calls to Reverse doesn't do any real work.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Guffa , really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that avoiding popping items off the stack will improve your code's performance more than the alternative between the two approaches you suggest. I would recommend allocating a new stack with the contents of the last item on the stack using linq like so:

```
var newStack = new Stack<FilterRecord>( 
   _InternalCollection.Take( 10 )
                      .Reverse() );

_InternalCollection = newStack;
```

If you're not using generics, you can do the same with the built in iterator:

```
var iterator = _InternalCollection.GetEnumerator();
int i = 9;
while( iterator.MoveNext() && i-- >= 0 )
{
   newStack.Push( iterator.Current );
}
_InternalCollection = newStack;
```

Comment: See comment to Guffa's suggestion

Comment: A few thoughts. Avoid sharing static collection in this manner - use a property to hide access and allow object instances to be substituted as needed. Second, since you already have such a scenario - avoid calling Pop() on the stack at all. Use an enumerator, copy the values into a temporary array. Use Clear() to wipe the stack (this is pretty quick). And then Push() the values back into the stack in reverse order. This is probably the quickest approach.

Comment: Thanks  LBushkin I understand what you mean about the use of static classes, I debated this in my head for some time. In the end the need to ensure that I had excactly one object in memory was the fator that swung the decision.

Answer (score 3):

Your first algorithm has two for-loops, so O(2N).  Your second algorithm has one for loop, but we have to assume that internally Reverse() is an O(N) operation, so its O(3N).

I'm not sure if the Clear() call is O(N) or O(C) in your first algorithm.

Comment: The for loops in the first algorithm are O(1), so it's only the call to Clear that is relevant for big O notation, which is an O(n) operation. The second algorithm is O(n-10), but for any large number the 10 would be negligible, so both alorithms are O(n).

Comment: How is a for loop that goes over every element in the collection an O(1) operation?

Answer (score 3):

It depends.  There's two things you can do:

- test it by running it for a couple
  hundred iterations (less or more
  depending on the size)
- look at their    implementations

Analyzing the method in which a stack is implemented (conceptually), **using reverse would be the slowest as it would have to pop everything of the stack, and then pop them back in**, in the opposite order.  If internally, it just selects a different starting index of where to start popping, it could be faster.

Either way, simply put, using Reverse() seems inefficient as you're performing that operation twice.

Answer (score 1):

If there are few items in the stack, there will be so little difference that it's not worth optimising.

If there are many items in the stack, this would be the fastest:

```
FilterRecord[] records = new FilterRecord[10];

for (int i = 0; i < records.Length; i++) {
   records[i] = _InternalCollection.Pop();
}

_InternalCollection = new Stack<FilterRecord>();

for (int i = records.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   _InternalCollection.Push(records[i]);
}
```

I.e. just throw away the current stack after you get the items that you want to keep, and let the garbage collector take care of it. If you use the Clear method, that will remove the references from the stack but it will keep it's capacity.

As you only touch ten of the items in the stack regardless of how many there are, this is an O(1) operation instead of an O(n) operation.

(Note that you use the size of the array when you declare it, not the hightest index.)

Comment: This could be even faster if you avoid popping the items off the original stack and just use an enumerator to visit each.

Comment: Look again... It's not popping all the items, only ten of them.

Comment: the problem is that the _InternalCollection is static there will be a number of object holding a reference to this collection

Comment: In that case, visit the first ten using an enumerator, copy them out. Clear the collection and re-add in reverse order from the copy. Avoid calling Pop() at all - Clear() is much faster.

Comment: Either refactor the code so that there is only one reference to the actual stack object (perhaps encapsulating it into another class), otherwise you have to take the hit of touching every item in the stack when you clear it.

Comment: @LBushkin: Whether an enumerator or Pop is used is irrelevant. It's only ten items, so that part of the operation is negligible compared to the operation of clearing out the stack. If the stack is so large that the performance is of relevance at all, the Clear method has to be avoided as that turns it from an O(1) operation to an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 0):

That depends, you're assuming that the Reverse() method isn't doing exactly that.  Only two ways to know: 1.) run your code and tell us 2.) look up the implementation of Reverse().

Answer (score 0):

Its often hard to tell on these types of things. Just make an insanely large stack, call both and time them. Then you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the actual implementation of Reverse() - you may find the [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) useful for that.

Answer (score 0):

How about not using a stack in the first place? How about wrapping a LinkedList and then use the RemoveLast method to do what you need?

Some rough code, needs more work, but you get the basic idea:

```
    public class CustomStack<T>
    {
        private LinkedList<T> list;

        public CustomStack()
        {
            list = new LinkedList<T>();
        }

        public void Push(T item)
        {
            list.AddFirst(item);
        }

        public T Pop()
        {

            var result = list.First.Value;
            list.RemoveFirst();
            return result;
        }

        public void TrimLast(int amountToLeave)
        {
            while (list.Count > amountToLeave)
            {
                list.RemoveLast();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can pretty much count on the Double reverse being slower.  Your running time for 1) is constant (O(1))  in terms of _InternalCollection.Length (assuming Clear is constant time) and O(n) in terms of the number of elements you want to keep. 2) will get slower, linearly the bigger _InternalCollection is (O(n))

You might also want to consider changing your _InternalCollection into a Deque (Double ended queue).  A Deque supports O(1) amortized time to add/remove items from either end.  Of course (AFAIK) there isn't a standard implementation so you would have to roll your own or [use a third party implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/deque.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I will look at the implementation

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` the last 10 items on the stack to where you want them to be.

Then declare the stack to be 10 items long.